# I can't get eager queries for entity collections to work in Gorm/Grails 3.3.9

Tags: associations, grails-orm, where-clause, eager-loading

I have a Domain model with OrgRoleInstance with hasMany= {sites:Site}, and Site domain entity with belongsTo =[org:OrgRoleInstance]

I don't want to use the static mapping = {} clause in the domain object as I want to control the fetch strategy via the queries.

I setup several unit tests like this and setup 3 orgs and one site each

```
void "list with eager fetch query"() {
    given :

    def orgs = OrgRoleInstance.list(fetch:[sites:"eager"])
    println "org b.sites : " + orgs[1].sites

    println "site #2  has org as : " + (Site.list())[1].org

    expect :
    Site.count() == 3
    orgs.size() == 3
    orgs[1].getName() == "B"
    orgs[1].sites.size() == 1

}

void "where query"() {
    given :

    def orgs = OrgRoleInstance.where {
        name =~ "%B%" &&
        sites{}
    }.list()

    expect :  //actual get null in orgs
    Site.count() == 3
    orgs[0].name == "B"
    orgs[0].sites.size() == 1

}

void "criteria query " () {
    given:

    OrgRoleInstance org

    org = OrgRoleInstance.withCriteria (uniqueResult: true) {
        //eq 'name', "B"
        and {
            idEq(2)
            eq ('name', "B")
        }
    }

    def orgs = OrgRoleInstance.withCriteria {
        eq 'name', "B"
        //fetchMode 'sites', FetchMode.SELECT
        sites{}
    }

    orgs

    expect:  //actual sites is size=0
    org.id == 2
    org.sites.size() == 1

}
```

What am I doing wrong - the middle test returns null from the query, the others return OrgRoleInstance but the sites property is 'empty'.

I have checked the setup and the sites are correctly saved and reference there org - so the domain model is correct.

What am I doing wrong when writing these queries?

PS I tried a where query from the many side and that does appear to work and load the parent site in the result.

```
//this one works
void "where query from the many side "() {
    given :

    def site = Site.where {
        org.id == 2
    }.list()

    expect :
    Site.count() == 3
    site.org.name == ["B"]

}
```

Comment: I just added a PS as when i write a where query from the many side - that test seems to load the parent Org as the test shows

Answer (score 0):

Essentially **unit** testing domain queries with new testing traits doesn't work.

If you want test your queries you have to write integration tests or use Grails console to have a play with a gorm env loaded.

[Related posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54325664/grails-3-3-9-unit-testing-cant-get-where-query-to-do-eager-loading-of-one-to).